# Marklogic error logs to log full line instead of truncated

Tags: marklogic

I am running some tasks in Task Server and using REST API from MarkLogic. When there is any error it is logged into a file. But log lines are truncated after it reaches a certain length. Is there any configuration to set the truncation limit?

I know I can use xdmp:describe in code but what I am looking for is if there is some config to set the limit for truncation.

Below is the truncated line from logs(some stuff obfuscated). See the dots at the end.

```
2019-07-12 09:27:15.768 Notice: ****: XDMP-AS: (err:XPTY0004) ****** -- Invalid coercion: "Could
 not unlock work item. The step is not a userTask, or status is..." as node()
```

Comment: I think group level log settings debug/finer/finest provide fuller log entries.  Not sure about other options.

Answer (score 0):

Log lines themselves are not truncated.  You can verify this by explicityly writing log entries -- they can be very VERY long.  However individual errors/exceptions can be truncated at the point of generation, most common is what ends up in stack traces.  You are likely hitting such a case where the specific exception error is truncated.  You MIGHT be able to work around this by using  a try/catch block which will preserver the full error as a structured value then log it yourself.